# Detect text length of div with class

Tags: jquery, text, string-length

I'm brand new to JQuery but have some JS experience.  Have inherited someone else's piece of work.

I'm trying to work out the character length of a div and then display a message if there's too many characters.

```
"selector":"div.info-box",
"filter": function(index,obj){
var boxlength = obj.text().length;
if(boxlength > 50){
return true;
}
return false;
},
"each":function(obj){
$(obj).css("border-bottom","dashed 1px red");
```

The filter is giving me issues.  If I remove the filter entirely then the specific div I want with a class of infobox is highlighted with a red dash (at least I know I have the selector correct).  How do I write the filter to detect more than 50 characters?
I need to retain the format of selector, filter, each.

Thankyou

Comment: And what plugin / language is this for ?

Comment: Looks like you did not provide us the whole javascript code you are using. This one is is not valid at all.

Comment: debugger is telling me the object var boxlength doesn't support the method or property, so I'll read that as I can't create a variable for div.info-box but don't know where to go from there.

Comment: there's too much other code to include, it's just the filter that's throwing me.  is it not normal?  sorry, I'm lost in JQuery.

Comment: Look at my answer. This is how it works with jQuery. But you should at least provide us valid code. Javascript does not start with `"selector":...`. Otherwise everyone just can guess what is your problem. What is the console.log() output for obj? Maybe it is no jQuery object?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance and thank you for your replies.

Comment: Oops, hit enter my mistake.  The plugin is Sizzle.

Comment: "selector":"#content p",
   "filter": function(index,obj){
    var html = obj.innerHTML;
    html = html.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
    if(obj.childNodes.length == 0 || html.match(/^[\s]*$/) ){
     return true;
    }
    return false;
   },
   "each":function(obj){
    $(obj).css("color","red");
    $(obj).html(" (empty paragraph) ");

Comment: ummm, the part above is an example of currently working code (that I inherited), hence the format of my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a shot into the dark:

```
$('div.info-box').on('<your action>', function(){
  if ($(this).val().length > 50)
  {
    alert('more than 50 characters');
  }
})
```

You should read more at [jquery.com](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply Jurik, much appreciated.  I replaced the lines of the variable and if statement with simnply - "if ($(obj).elements[0].innerHTML.length > 250)" and it works perfectly

Comment: @user3518221 It would be nice to mark my answer as correct :)